# Is it possible to completely mask an IP address to a point where no IP address can be detected yet an active connection is live?

Tags: ip, vpn, network, security

I’ll keep it short and sweet;

We all know to connect to internet you’ll need an address like `2001:x**` or `192.x**.`

Using a vpn, while it does encrypt things and mask your IP, it still returns an IP.

What I want to know is: is it possible to hide an IP behind an encrypted string like ; `0xFF7mXeFxb55klKEzVcb27`

While it sounds far fetched I want to know if it would ever be possible because it enables a higher level of anonymity and encryption.

Comment: Packet headers have both the source and destination IP addresses, which are 32-bit (IPv4) or 128-bit (IPv6) unsigned integers. They are not the text representations as you show, but actual binary numbers. Changing from one address to another address in a packet header is called NAT.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

When you establish a connection and ask a server to send you information, the server must know where to send the answer. So it needs to know your IP address.

Even in the few cases where you send an information and don't require any response, this is simply not how the IP protocol works. A packet always contains the source and destination IP addresses, even if one of these if obfuscated with another one.

Comment: The server needs *AN* address, not necessarily my *actual* address. This is part of the purpose of proxies and VPN services. (see also: Tor)

Answer (score 0):

> We all know to connect to internet you’ll need an address like 2001:x** or 192.x**.

Wrong. To participate on the Internet you require a *public* IP address - any address not reserved from public use and usually provided by your ISP.

If you locally use a private IPv4 address (from 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, or 192.168.0.0/16 per RFC 1918) that address must be translated to a valid public IP address using source NAT before being sent to the Internet.

> Using a vpn, while it does encrypt things and mask your IP, it still returns an IP.

You seem to mean a *VPN service* that provides you with another public IP address, different from your ISP's. "returns an IP" address seems to refer to "use a public IP address that's visible to the outside" - yes, that is required for Internet communication, see above.

Normally, VPN links provide private and encrypted links across an untrusted network like the Internet. The tunneling is also used to transport incompatible addresses (e.g. private addresses over public address space).

> What I want to know is: is it possible to hide an IP behind an encrypted string like ; 0xFF7mXeFxb55klKEzVcb27

No. IP addresses on the Internet cannot be encrypted in any way. A packet's source IP address must be valid to the destination in order to return a reply.